# Can google detect tor browser

Tags: encryption, web-application

Usually while we browse Google through our IP we will be redirected to respective countries. I normally use **tor browser** for anonymity. Today while I browsed google I got redirected to `encrypted.google.com`.

Does this mean google can detect tor browser?
If yes, **how do they detect our browser identity and IP**?

<sub>Note: if we browse using proxy sites we are not redirected towards their encrypted website.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because Google detected you as Tor user. It's because the tor browser is shipped with many security plugins pre-installed. [One of them](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) is to always use HTTPS for supported website likes Facebook, Google etc.

You can also use Google's Encrypted search by:

1. opening Google with HTTPS like https://www.google.com
2. access google at encrypted.google.com and it will turn on HTTPS

Both above method makes your connection secure by using HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP. You can install that plugin in you Firefox also as you do install other plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Any web site can determine which of their visitors are using Tor, because a comprehensive list of Tor node IP addresses is a public part of the Tor network's operation. What actions a website takes based on that information is out of your control, so you can only expect the worst, whatever that may be.

Answer (score -2):

com in your URL Box it could certainly redirect to encrypted.google.com but when you instead type www.google.us or www.google.fr etc..
you will redirect to respective Country domain and respective IP Adress

And can you say that google can know that we are using TOR Browser No way !